# Measuring the delay between POST was sent and the webserver starts PHP processing?

Tags: php, performance, apache, nginx

When fighting performance problems, a common issue is: The problems are not reliable. One time, there is a delay and when you test it by yourself, it's gone. Even worse: Server monitoring does not capture such problems accurately. If only 1 on 20 requests is slow, it is unlikely (5%) that a 10-minute monitoring will show the delays.

What I am currently searching for: Can I measure the delay between a client sending the GET/POST request for a PHP script and the webserver processing the request. Ideally from the **PHP script**. Or put in other words: It there any chance to find out **when** the POST/GET request was submitted **by the browser**? Or at least, when the server (Apache or NGINX) received the requests' first byte?

The delays I'd like to monitor, are quite large: 5 or 10 seconds. So a resultion of seconds would be good enough. Any ideas?

BurninLeo

Comment: PS: I was already considering a solution that sent the server timestamp along the previous page, and started a JavaScript on the client to send a sent-time estimate along the next POST. Of course, such a measure would not be possible before the second request, and it is quite complicated :(

Comment: Since your server knows nothing of any incoming request until it actually arrived at the server, that's pretty much impossible to do. If the time between the first byte and the end of the request was long, that could be measured. But if the time of the first byte to arrive is long, that's not really possible to measure for the first request without having some measuring code running on the client itself. You could check for the client's `Date` HTTP header, but for this to be useful the server and client clocks would have to run in sync perfectly.

Comment: Actually I am quite sure that it's no transmission problem, but there is a very long delay between the request arriving at the server and the start of processing. My problem is: From PHP I can neither access the HTTP header nor does Apache or NGINX tell me about the arrival (as far as I know)...

Comment: You may be interested in $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']

Comment: Also as of Apache 2.4 it has mod_lua and you may try writing handler that will record or even append to your get requests appropriate timestamp for you to verify

Comment: @Artur: Thanks for your suggestions. I shall indeed have a look at mod_lua - that seems interesting. You do no accidentially know, if REQUEST_TIME is the time when the request arrived on the server *or* at the PHP processor, do you? The PHP manual is a bit unspecific, here.

Comment: @BurninLeo: Best way to check would be to compare REQUEST_TIME with microtime from the begining of the short script.